# How can I use the response data after an axios call to display video in React?

Tags: reactjs, mp4

I use react for frontend.
I get an mp4 video file from an axios call:

```
const onGetVideo = () => {
axiosClient.get(`/solution/video.mp4`)
  .then(({ data }) => {
    console.log(data)
    // data here is simple binary data 
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  })
}
```

How can I use the response (data) to display the video on the website?

Comment: why not use `<video controls> <source src="/solution/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" /></video>`

Comment: Because the video is stored in the storage folder in Laravel and cannot be accessed directly. After calling the '/solution/video.mp4' route the controller responds with the video requested in binary data form. That's why I mentioned: "// data here is simple binary data "

Answer (score 2):

I have found this solution:

```
const [videoSource, setVideoSource] = useState(null);

const onGetVideo = () => {
  axiosClient.get(`/solution/video.mp4`, { responseType: 'blob' })
    .then(({ data }) => {
      const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(data);
      setVideoSource(blobUrl);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });

useEffect(() => {onGetVideo()}, []);

return( ...
    <video controls>
      <source src={videoSource} type="video/mp4" />
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video> ...)
```

I have to specify responseType: 'blob' to get binary data.

When the data is received, I create a Blob URL using URL.createObjectURL(data) and set it as the video source.

Answer (score 1):

could you share the format of the data "response"

if you data response is, in this format then,

data = [{video_url: ""}]
then try this,

const video = data[0].video_url  // (here your video url is stored ini the video variable)

install: npm install react-player
add this line in your file : import ReactPlayer from 'react-player'
add this code:

Comment: The response is simple binary data.